# How can I query by property type rather than type name using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following `DbContext`, where each `DbSet` marked with a `// This` comment is a potential target for my `GetDbSetsByType` method. How can I query on actual type in my `.Any` lambda rather than type name? When I use `t => t is T` it always fails. I assume this is because the lambda parameter is declared as `Type`.

```
public class CtsDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; } // This.
    public DbSet<JobLevel> JobLevels { get; set; } // This.
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; } // This.

    public IEnumerable<DbSet<T>> GetDbSetsByType<T>() where T : class
    {
        // Get one of the above DbSets based on its type.
        var tName = typeof (T).Name;
        var props = GetType().GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("DbSet"))
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Any(t => t.Name == tName));
        return props.Select(p => (DbSet<T>)p.GetValue(this, null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `t` is an instance of `System.Type` and `T` is a type, you should write:

```
t => t == typeof(T)
```

Instead of:

```
t => t is T
```